# Create dotted "trail" after div when moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a heavily modified version of the menu used in this [demo](http://www.aaronlumsden.com/articles/recreate-paths-ios-style-navigation-using-html-css3-jquery/):

When the smaller circles fan out, I want to place multiple small "dots" in between the central main item and the smaller outer circles, which would form a dotted line connecting the two items.

It would have an effect similar to this, but multiple times in a radial pattern (orange circles):

[image: Sketch of the above demo with desired circles in orange]

What would be the best way to accomplish this dynamically?

Comment: Added sketch. You expect this? -- What have you tried so far (code, libraries that can do such animation)? Should the (orange) circles have physical effects like flexibility/bending/wobbling or should they move static. Please edit your question and add these additions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created [a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MvRbQ/1/) with animation that you will need. Here's how it's done:

Create orange dots with radial gradient background and repeat it:

```
background: radial-gradient(circle, orange 5px, transparent 5px) 15px 0;
background-size: 20px 10px;
```

Rotate the element:

```
transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

When back circles fly out, change element width, use transition to make it smooth. In my example I've used animation, but there is no big difference.

```
transition: width 2s;
```

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily for this kind of thing, I'd suggest using a library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com). Using a graphics library to render graphical effects rather than the HTML DOM does tend to make things easier, particularly as things get more complex, and it's also a lot more flexible with the things it can achieve. The Raphael site has plenty of demos of what it's capable of doing, and I would say that an effect like this would be pretty easy once you'd got the hang of the Raphael API. The downside is that if you take this path, you'd probably have to write the whole menu using Raphael, so you'd be throwing away what you've got already and starting from scratch.

So therefore in this case, since you've already got a working demo that just uses regular HTML elements, you may as well work with what you've got. It doesn't seem like it should be too hard to modify it; just add an extra few sets of elements layered behind the main menu elements, and set them to animate at the same speed as the menu element they're following, but less distance.

It's quite a bit of extra markup, but should do the trick just fine. I'm not going to give you detailed instructions because there's probably a hundred ways of doing it; and I don't have time to come up with a whole tutorial, but at the end of the day, it should just be little more than a case of copy+paste. Not the most elegant way of writing code, but it should work. The only caveat I can foresee is that it might slow things down if you have five times as many things being animated on screen at the same time. But that can be worked on once you've got the thing working.